# extracting information from a column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a file which looks like this:

```
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-202"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
```

I want to extract gene_id and gene_name values along with first 8 columns(file is tab separated). I have written a script in perl which can do this, but I am looking for a one liner in awk,sed etc which can do this.

PS. The file is tab separated and has 9 columns. The 9 th column has values which are separated by spaces.

My output should look like this:

```
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .   +   .   ENSG00000223972.5   DDX11L1
```

Comment: Why can't you just print columns 1-8, 10 and 16 with `awk` ?

Comment: meaning using field separator as space and tab?

Comment: I updated the post. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: OK, so if none of those keys and values in your file contains spaces then you can do as I said above, using the default field separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `awk` script assumes that the 9th column could have data in any order.

The code will split the column on `;` followed by an optional space.  It will then iterate over the resulting elements and split these on spaces into a key value pair.  If the key (the thing to the left of the space) is any of the two strings `gene_id` or `gene_name`, the value for this key is remembered.  The parsing of the 9th column ends when we have found our two strings, after which the column is rewritten and the modified line is printed.

The code also discards any input that does *not* contain both `gene_id` and `gene_name`.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}

{
    n = split($9, a, "; ?")

    found = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        if (split(a[i], b, " ") == 2) {
            if (b[1] == "gene_id") {
                gene_id = b[2]
                ++found
            } else if (b[1] == "gene_name") {
                gene_name = b[2]
                ++found
            }

            if (found == 2) break
        }

    if (found == 2) {
        $9 = gene_id " " gene_name
        print
    }
}
```

Testing on the data provided:

```
$ awk -f script.awk <file
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .       +       .       "ENSG00000223972.5" "DDX11L1"
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .       +       .       "ENSG00000223972.5" "DDX11L1"
```

To remove the double quotes from the values, change

```
if (found == 2) {
    $9 = gene_id " " gene_name
    print
}
```

into

```
if (found == 2) {
    gsub("\"", "", gene_id)
    gsub("\"", "", gene_name)
    $9 = gene_id " " gene_name
    print
}
```

which removes all double quotes from the gene name and ID, or,

```
if (found == 2) {
    gene_id = substr(gene_id, 2, length(gene_id) - 2)
    gene_name = substr(gene_name, 2, length(gene_name) - 2)
    $9 = gene_id " " gene_name
    print
}
```

which removes the first and last characters from the two values.

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner. It can be golfed a bit shorter, but I think this is pretty clear.

```
perl -F'\t' -lane '
    if (($id, $name) = / \b gene_id \s+ " ([^"]+) .+ \b gene_name \s+ " ([^"]+)/x) {
        print join "\t", @F[0..7], $id, $name;
    }
' file
```

A little more "clever":

```
perl -F'\t' -E '$,="\t"; say @F[0..7], $g{id}, $g{name} if %g = /\bgene_(id|name)\s+"([^"]+)/g' file
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain `[^"]+` in the first code??

Comment: One or more of any character _except double quote_.

Answer (score 1):

`awk '{ print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $7 "\t" $8 "\t" $10 "\t" $16 ; } ' filename > output`

without quotes and semicolons :

`awk '{ print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $7 "\t" $8 "\t" $10 "\t" $16 ; }' filename | sed -e 's/;//g; s/\"//g;' > output`

more accurate using only awk:

`awk '{ ORS=" "; print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $6 "\t" $7 "\t" $8 "\t"; gsub(";", "", $10); gsub("\"", "", $10); print $10 "\t"; gsub(";", "", $16) ; gsub("\"", "", $16); print $16 ; ORS="\n" ; print " "; } ' filename > output`